# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double

Tags: android, google-maps, location, number-formatting

I have a method to calculate Difference between two Latitude:

```
public static double distanceKM(LatLng latLng1, LatLng latLng2) {
    int EARTH_RADIUS_KM = 6371;
    double lat1Rad = Math.toRadians(latLng1.latitude);
    double lat2Rad = Math.toRadians(latLng2.latitude);
    double deltaLonRad = Math.toRadians(latLng2.longitude - latLng1.longitude);

    double dist_travelled = Math
            .acos(Math.sin(lat1Rad) * Math.sin(lat2Rad) + Math.cos(lat1Rad)
                    * Math.cos(lat2Rad) * Math.cos(deltaLonRad))
            * EARTH_RADIUS_KM;

    dist_travelled = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.######")
            .format(dist_travelled));

    return dist_travelled;

}
```

Sometimes, this method throw Exception (I say sometimes, when I test in defference device):

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "0,179927"
>                                                                         at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
>                                                                         at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:269)

Can someone help me in this case? Thanks

Comment: your dist_travelled value contains ,(comma) check your dist_travelled properly

Comment: But i format  dist_travelled (double with type ##.####), . not , , why when i format again, . switch to , ?

Comment: you don't need to convert again. but you need to check why dist_travelled gives ,(comma)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of the double depends on the language of the device. For example, for devices in french the number *0.179927* becomes *0,179927* which will always throw a `NumberFormatException` when parsing it to `double` because of the comma.

You need to change the separator from a `comma` to a `point`.
You can change the separator either by setting a locale or using the `DecimalFormatSymbols`.

If you want the grouping separator to be a point, you can use a european locale:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
```

Alternatively you can use the `DecimalFormatSymbols` class to change the symbols that appear in the formatted numbers produced by the `format` method. These symbols include the decimal separator, the grouping separator, the minus sign, and the percent sign, among others:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(currentLocale);
otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
otherSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('.'); 
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(formatString, otherSymbols);
```